# Does My Array To Many Dimension?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code :

```
<?php

$res = array ( array ('vendor_id' => '21',
                      'box_1' => array ([0]=>array('product_id' => '80', 'pcs' => '1'),
                                        [1]=>array('product_id' => '85', 'pcs' => '5')),
                      'box_2' => array ([0]=>array('product_id' => '80', 'pcs' => '3'),
                                        [1]=>array('product_id' => '92', 'pcs' => '9'))
             ));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);

?>
```

and it produce this error message :

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in /home/***/public_html/***.php on line 4

Warning: Illegal offset type in /home/***/public_html/***.php on line 5

Warning: Illegal offset type in /home/***/public_html/***.php on line 6

Warning: Illegal offset type in /home/***/public_html/***.php on line 7
```

what's wrong with my array? why I got that error message. thanks before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to specify index's `[0]` and `[1]` . try this

```
<?php

$res = array ( array ('vendor_id' => '21',
                      'box_1' => array (array('product_id' => '80', 'pcs' => '1'),
                                        array('product_id' => '85', 'pcs' => '5')),
                      'box_2' => array (array('product_id' => '80', 'pcs' => '3'),
                                        array('product_id' => '92', 'pcs' => '9'))
             ));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);

?>
```

if you want to specify the array key you dont need to write [] like Matei Mihai suggestion.

And if the array key you want to specify is string then you can enclose it with 
`'` e.g=> `'key_name'` or 
`"` e.g=> `"key_name"`

```
$res = array ( array ('vendor_id' => '21',
                    'box_1' => array (
                                        0 => array('product_id' => '80', 'pcs' => '1'),
                                        1 => array('product_id' => '85', 'pcs' => '5')
                    ),
                    'box_2' => array (
                                        0 => array('product_id' => '80', 'pcs' => '3'),
                                        1 => array('product_id' => '92', 'pcs' => '9')
                    )
        ));
echo '<pre>';print_r($res); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
[0] => array('product_id' => '80', 'pcs' => '1')
```

you must use only the numeric part as key:

```
0 => array('product_id' => '80', 'pcs' => '1')
```

Of course, the numeric key is not mandatory. You can add those arrays without using any key.

Answer (score 2):

```
'box_1' => array ([0]=>array('product_id' => '80', 'pcs' => '1'),
```

There is your mistake:

`[0]` is an array containing the number 0.
You can not have an Array as Key inside another Array. Either use just the number `0` or the string `"0"`